# insert many not working in mongoDB using mongoos

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

could you please tell me  why insert many not working in MongoDB using mongoos

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-solomon-o91wp
It only inserts one row ,not multiple

```
app.get("/saveData", async () => {
  try {
    const data = [
      {
        empid: "test123",
        date: "19-Jul-2019"
      },
      {
        empid: "test13",
        date: "18-Jul-2019"
      }
    ];
    console.log("before save");
    let saveBlog = await BlogPostModel.collection.insertMany(data, {
      checkKeys: false
    }); //when fail its goes to catch
    console.log(saveBlog); //when success it print.
    console.log("saveBlog save");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per  https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-solomon-o91wp
This will not work because your id is unique in your schema and you try to add data with undefined id

```
// your data as per https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-solomon-o91wp
const data = [
  {
    empid: "test123",
    date: "19-Jul-2019"
  },
  {
    empid: "test13",
    date: "18-Jul-2019"
  },

  {
    empid: "test13",
    date: "11-Jul-2019"
  }
];
```

Solution
Change your data like as follows

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    empid: "test123",
    date: "19-Jul-2019"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
    empid: "test13",
    date: "18-Jul-2019"
  },
  {
    id: "3"
    empid: "test13",
    date: "11-Jul-2019"
  }
];
```